# Hide button based on session value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying to hide various buttons dependant on the users permissions
How can I hide this button if a session value Session("IsMaster") is false. I'm using vb.net MVC and still learning

```
    <a Class="btn btn-default"  href='@Url.Action("Index", "OriginatingAccounts")'>
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Operator.png")' />
        Originating Accounts &raquo;
    </a>
```

Comment: Do you mean permissions related to UAC ?

Comment: When a user logs into the system, a session variable is created as a boolean. when accessing 'web page' I want to hide / show certain buttons based on the value of the session variable